# Need to fix the date in some bad data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, replace

downloaded some YAHOO stock data and the date is messed up showing as 2065-01-04 instead of 1965-01-04

Date    Open    High    Low 
2065-01-04  84.750000   85.150002   83.769997

I tried to iterate through that column but I dont know how to only replace the 2 in 2065, 2066, 2055 etc because the dataset also have downloaded some YAHOO stock data and the date is messed up showing as 2065-01-04 instead of 1965-01-04

Date        Open        High        Low 
2065-01-04  84.750000   85.150002   83.769997

I tried to iterate through that column but I dont know how to only replace the 2 in 2065, 2066, 2055.  What makes this even more complicated is that the same dataset also have 2000-2019, which don’t need to be replaced.  However after further digging I found that the date goes back to normal at 1969 which is line 981.

I guess I can slice out the 1000 bad rows but I was hoping to salvage them if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
         date    price
0  2055-02-24  4124.25
1  2066-02-25  4130.67
2  2019-02-27  4180.10
3  2019-02-28  4200.05
4  2067-01-03  4210.12
```

By doing this simple trick:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(x[:2],'19') if int(x[:4])>2019 else x)

         date    price
0  1955-02-24  4124.25
1  1966-02-25  4130.67
2  2019-02-27  4180.10
3  2019-02-28  4200.05
4  1967-01-03  4210.12
```

You should be able to do this yourself by adjusting your criteria. But remember to do `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` later on